# Fetch specific data from Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fetch

There is a database named userdetails of three columns name, email, and password. How can I fetch only name from Firebase Firestore? Please give an example.

I have stucked in that thing(fetching of specific data)

Comment: In server-side environments you can use `select` for that. In client-side SDKs, that option doens't exist and you always get the full document.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you can't do that with a server side query. A firebase query would return the DocumentSnapshot.

On the client side you would map that to what you need.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: A good example is under the custom objects section of the above link. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects. Essentially convert the returned document to a map and access the fields needed through that.